# box() outline only at top and bottom

Tags: r

Okay, I'm stupid, but **how can I get R to draw the lines of the `box()` only at the top and bottom?**

I understand that with `bty` I can influence the shape, but there does not seem to be an option for top or bottom or top & bottom. All I can do with `bty` are two or three adjacent sides (L or U shape), but not a single or two opposing sides.

The problem is that when I draw an `abline` at the plot area edge the line lies half under that edge and is only half as thick as lines farther inside the plot (see image below), but moving the `abline` slightly towards the center of the plot will make it no longer align with the axis ticks and labels and cause unequal distances between my "grid". Drawing a line outside the plot area with `par(xpd = NA)` will not limit it to the plot area size and the line then runs through the label.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only reproduce your problem if `lwd=2`. So for that case, perhaps you can try this.

```
plot(0:10, axes=F, type='n', yaxs='i',xlab='y', ylab='x')
```

Add axes with tick lengths of 0 and without labels and square line ends:

```
lims=par("usr")
axis(1, lwd.ticks=0, lab=F, at=lims[1:2], lwd=2, lend=1)
axis(3, lwd.ticks=0, lab=F, at=lims[1:2], lwd=2, lend=1)
abline(h=1:9, lwd=2, lend=1)
axis(2, las=1, tick=F)
```

[image: top and bottom lines]

Comment: That does not solve the problem. Change your code to `abline(h=c(lims[3:4], 1:9))` and you will see that the outer ablines are thinner than the inner ablines. If you draw ablines exactly at the limit of the plot area, their thickness lies half in, half out the plot area. And I don't want to increase `ylim`because then the tips of the vertical ablines become visible beyond the top and bottom horizontal ablines. Of course I can fiddle with this until it looks okay, but I don't want to do that because it will break and require renewed fiddling every time I change anything.

Comment: For me, this only happens when lwd=2 and only to the top line. I changed my answer to be valid for that case as well.

Comment: Nice. But try `abline(h=seq(0.1, 9.9, 0.1), lwd=2, lend=2)`. The axis appears to be half its width longer than the plot area. The sides of a box are longer, too (try `box(bty="c", lwd=2, lend=2)` in stead of the axes), so I'm gonna accept this answer as equivalent to top and bottom box sides.

Comment: You're right. The first point (longer axes) can be addressed by choosing `lend=1`.